# QProcess doesn't get finished signal from x-terminal-emulator

Tags: qt, ubuntu, terminal

I try running **x-terminal-emulator** with QProcess (Ubuntu).

```
process->setWorkingDirectory(thedirectory);
process->start("x-terminal-emulator",arg3);
connect(process,SIGNAL(finished(int)),this,SLOT(deletecache()));
```

when it is run, `deletecache()` is executed as soon as terminal window open.
if I change the `start` to `execute`, there's no finished signal emmitted.
how to get the `finished(int)` signal when the terminal window closed?

Comment: No idea, but it is a bad idea to connect after the invocation.

Comment: Maybe it's because `x-terminal-emulator` is a script that runs the real terminal process and exits.

Comment: @PavelStrakhov: yeah, true, the only reason I can think of is a detached script process for the real executable. Is that the case here miraiE?

Comment: I think x-terminal-emulator is a pseudo command in Linux which can refer to Konsole in KDE, gnome-terminal in Gnome, XTerm, or else.

Answer (score 0):

> when it is run, deletecache() is executed as soon as terminal window open.

I will assume that arg3 points to your script that x-terminal-emulator will run. The only reason for that happening is that if your script makes the invokation for the external program as a detached process in the background since then it would not block until you close, but would return instantly.

> if I change the start to execute, there's no finished signal emmitted.

That is expected since execute() is a static method and there is no such a concept as static signal-slot.

> how to get the finished(int) signal when the terminal window closed?

Do not run the terminal as a detached background process.

Comment: arg3 is a QStringList. I don't know whether x-terminal-emulator run in separate process. but I assume it is linked to another program and execute the program when it is called.

Comment: I'm sorry for my late respond. It's not already resolved, and I leave it for now. Thanks.